# Amazon Lambda - Creating object takes too long

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a simple lambda function that create a new file on a S3 bucket. I've already configured the security policies and I think that it should work but it takes too long.

**The code is this**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import boto3

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 = " + event['key3'])

    bucket_name = 'lambda-demo2016'
    file_name = 'hello.txt'
    path = '/tmp/' + file_name

    # Create file
    file = open(path, 'wb')
    file.write("Hello World!!!")
    file.close()

    # Create Connection
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    s3_client.put_object(Body=open(path), Key='hello', Bucket=bucket_name)

    return event['key1'] #just return something...
```

I've got this:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2016-05-10T21:01:11.689Z 47160213-16f2-11e6-8e41-8f6a61b4b42e Task timed out after 20.00 seconds"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should this take too long?

Comment: Did you enable VPC access? If so did you create an S3 VPC endpoint?

Comment: Yes, and I've also checked the policies and the security groups.

Comment: There is something in your network configuration that is incorrect. I would go through everything on this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html#vpc-endpoints-routing there are quite a few things you have to configure correctly on your VPC for your application to be able to access the S3 endpoint.

Comment: What does the number of VPCs have to do with anything? I suggest you read the entire page I linked.

Comment: Do you actually need VPC access for your Lambda function? Because your current code doesn't need it, and would most likely work if you removed VPC access.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've removed the VPC and it worked!!

Comment: In which cases it is really needed to assign a VPC on a lambda function?

Comment: When you need to access resources that are private to the vpc.

Answer (score 1):

I would bump the timeout even higher just to see if it completes. Also adding some additional print statements in the code might show you where it is hanging.

Changing timeout for Lambda function is done under Lambda -> Functions -> Function -> Configuration -> Advanced Settings

[image]

Comment: To make it work longer is not a solution. It is supposed to be a very simple function.
I've already tried adding comments and the put_object function is not finishing. If you put a timeout longer than 60 seconds, you can't get all of the errors.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer that increasing timeout wasnt intended to be a solution, merely a troubleshooting technique to hopefully lead you to a solution, as your original post did not have a lot of information to go on. Glad you got your problem solved. Cheers!